# How to AUTOMATICALLY update a value of a column based on condition on another table's column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

So basically, I'm using Postgresql and what I want to do is this:
Say, we have 2 tables, the inventory and buyList

```
create table inventory
(item_id serial primary key,
name text not null,
quantity int not null,
price int not null);

insert into inventory values
(1,'a',44,10000),
(2,'b',12,12000),
(3,'c',11,5000),
(4,'d',6,3000);

create table buyList
(buy_id serial primary key,
item_id not null references inventory(item_id),
quantity int not null);

insert into buyList values
(1,2,4),
(2,2,5),
(3,1,1);
```

so I want to have the inventory.quantity value to be subtracted by the buyList.quantity of relevant item (based of item_id ofcourse)
for example, when there is someone who buy 4 of item 'a', then the value of item 'a' quantity column in table inventory will be 40 (automatically updated).

EDIT :
THANKS A LOT to krithikaGopalakrisnan for the answer, 
so I use the trigger made by krithikaGopalakrisnan (and modified it a little)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$ 
    BEGIN 

    UPDATE inventory SET quantity =  quantity-NEW.quantity WHERE inventory.item_id = NEW.item_id ;

     RETURN NEW;
    END; 
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
DECLARE 
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON buylist FOR EACH ROW  WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger()');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But now a new problem arises, when the quantity of the item in inventory table (inventory.quantity) is 0, and there is a new purchase of that item in the buylist table, the inventory.quantity of that item becomes a negative number! (of course we can't have that), how do I fix this so that when the item quantity is 0 in the inventory table, the buylist table can't accept another tuple indicating someone buying that item (maybe a function to return error message or something)

thanks in advance, I am still a total novice so I will really appreciate any help and guidance from you guys.

Comment: So what do you want to make? Compute column, trigger, or select statement?

Comment: trigger maybe? I'm not so sure actually, so basically, when I insert a new tuple in buyList table (meaning someone is buying something), the quantity of that something is automatically subtracted based on how many that something is bought. Really sorry if I didn't explain well

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is what u need..

```
    CREATE FUNCTION trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$ 
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE inventory SET quantity =  NEW.quantity WHERE inventory.item_id = NEW.item_id;
    RETURN NEW;
    END; 
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
DECLARE 
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON buylist FOR EACH ROW  WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger()');
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Sample data:

postgres=# select * from inventory;
 item_id | name | quantity | price 
---------+------+----------+-------
       1 | a    |       44 | 10000
       2 | b    |       12 | 12000
       3 | c    |       11 |  5000
       4 | d    |        6 |  3000
(4 rows)

postgres=# select * from buylist;
 buy_id | item_id | quantity 
--------+---------+----------
      1 |       2 |        4
      2 |       2 |        5
      3 |       1 |        1
(3 rows)

postgres=# update buylist set quantity=4 where item_id=1;

postgres=# select * from inventory;
 item_id | name | quantity | price 
---------+------+----------+-------
       2 | b    |       12 | 12000
       3 | c    |       11 |  5000
       4 | d    |        6 |  3000
       1 | a    |       40 | 10000
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks so so much, you really help me, but i just realize another problem, I edited my question a little bit. Hope you can help again